# Wideband metamaterials in mobile-telecommunications bands

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, conductors, antennas

Were there any [metamaterials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) (materials, settings, geometry) studied that are non-resonant (not frequency selective) in the frequencies between 700 MHz and 2700 MHz, therefore useful for mobile telecommunication purposes? I've been reading a lot of literature lately, but it seems that either they are used for lasers, or the selectivity is so high that they are used as "selective" filters. I'd want a metamaterial instead that has low losses on the above mentioned band.

Comment: What application is your metamaterial for? Are you specifically looking for a negative refractive index material?

Comment: I would like to study their uses actually... Nothing special. For example what happens to a beam if you put a metamaterials radome over it and so on

Answer (score 0):

Nonresonant metamaterials of course exist and are used; then denoted as "artificial dielectrics", they found their application in 1940s for construction of lightweight microwave optics. Their theory is even older:Lord Rayleigh theoretically elaborated the elmg/acoustic wave propagation through a rectangular lattice of cylindrical or spherical "obstacles" in 1892: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/14786449208620364

Note that the terminology is a bit obsoleted - for the Bloch wave in periodic media, the scattering particles are no "obstacles" in the classical sense.

In the nonresonant structures, you may generally engineer the permittivity tensor, with the possibility of constructing a strongly anisotropic or even hyperbolic medium. One example is the microwave wire polarizer.

Thanks to being far from resonance, the losses can be kept very low, unlike negative-index metamaterials which tend to be relatively lossy.